# How to pass variable key value in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Am trying to get the items from DynamoDB table based on the current date. Using the date value in string format when am trying to run the below piece of code, its error out saying:

{

"errorMessage": "ERROR: Dynamo failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'datatype' of undefined"

}

Below is the piece of code:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log("Request received:\n", JSON.stringify(event));
    console.log("Context received:\n", JSON.stringify(context));

var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamodb = new doc.DynamoDB();

var  params = {
Key: {
     "abc" : datetime1
},
TableName: 'myTable',
ProjectionExpression: 'message'
};

var Message = callback();
var datetiem = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    console.log('date is ', datetiem); // prints 2018-01-09

var datetime1 = JSON.stringify(datetiem);    
console.log(datetime1); //prints "2018-01-09"

function callback (message) {
dynamodb.getItem(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
           context.fail('ERROR: Dynamo failed: ' + err);
        } else {
         console.log('Dynamo Success: ' + JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
                 console.log('data', data)
                  let Message = data['Item'].message;
                    console.log('test',Message);
         }

  });
}
};
```

It runs fine if I pass the value directly i.e.  "abc" : "2018-01-09"
Can someone please advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure your datetime1 variable is defined when you use it in parameters. Try this:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log("Request received:\n", JSON.stringify(event));
    console.log("Context received:\n", JSON.stringify(context));

var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamodb = new doc.DynamoDB();

var Message = callback();
var datetiem = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    console.log('date is ', datetiem); // prints 2018-01-09

var datetime1 = JSON.stringify(datetiem);    
console.log(datetime1); //prints "2018-01-09"

var  params = {
Key: {
     "abc" : datetime1
},
TableName: 'myTable',
ProjectionExpression: 'message'
};

function callback (message) {
dynamodb.getItem(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
           context.fail('ERROR: Dynamo failed: ' + err);
        } else {
         console.log('Dynamo Success: ' + JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
                 console.log('data', data)
                  let Message = data['Item'].message;
                    console.log('test',Message);
         }

  });
}
};
```

Comment: Thanks Stu!! I have already tried this as well i.e. moving the param parameter after getting the variable value but it causes more errors to occur:                      {
  "errorMessage": "ERROR: Dynamo failed: MultipleValidationErrors: There were 2 validation errors:\n* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'TableName' in params\n* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Key' in params"
}

Comment: Ok, I got it. We need to get the variable value generated before it's passed to param and then call the function i.e. var Message = callback(); after the param variable and working fine. You are right, datetime1 is not required. Thanks Stu for all your help!!!